# Export to CSV a Symfony entity

Tags: php, symfony, csv, doctrine-orm

I want to export to a CSV a symfony entity. I have this code for the moment :

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();

    $iterableResult = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Member')
            ->createQueryBuilder('m')
            ->where('m.association = :id')
            ->setParameter('id', $id)
            ->getQuery()
            ->iterate();

    $handle = fopen('php://memory', 'r+');
    $header = array();

    while (false !== ($row = $iterableResult->next())) {
        dump($row[0]);
        fputcsv($handle, $row[0]);
        $em->detach($row[0]);
    }

    rewind($handle);
    $content = stream_get_contents($handle);
    fclose($handle);

    return new Response($content, 200, array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/force-download',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="export.csv"'
    ));
```

But I have this error :

```
Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, object given
```

As you can see, I dump $row[0] for debug :

> Member {#1360 ▼
>    -association: Association {#1444 ▶}
>    -locality: Locality {#1421 ▶}
>     -salutation: Salutation {#1409 ▶}
>     -country: Country {#1454 ▶}
>     -id: 844
>     -name: "TestName"
>     -firstname: "TestFirstname"
>     -date: DateTime {#1362 ▶}
>     -email: "email@domain.com"
>     -phone: "123456789"
>     -address: "Road 4, CH"
>     -description: null
>   }

I think the problem is because I have object in my object. What is the correct way to export an entity with object inside ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

No, the problem is exactly what the warning says: [fputcsv()](http://php.net/fputcsv) expects the 2nd parameter to be an array and you're passing it an object (in this case, based on your dump output, an instance of `Member`)

To fix it you'd at the very least need to cast your object to an array

```
fputcsv($handle, (array) $row[0]);
```

Or implement something like `Member::toArray()` and use that

```
fputcsv($handle, $row[0]->toArray());
```

Or, implement a library that helps you do this like [CSV from the PHP League](http://csv.thephpleague.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have use the [sonata-exporter bundle](https://github.com/sonata-project/exporter)

It's work now